# preloader image in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there any one who can help me out to use pre-loader image in my magento website. please click http://www.sweetfrost.in

Answer (score 0):

There is a FREE Image Loader (called Lazy Loader) extension available, check here: https://www.mgt-commerce.com/magento-lazy-load-images.html

For Demo : http://lazyloader.mgt-commerce.com/electronics/computers.html

Comment: Does this help to add pre-loader feature ?